# VS2008 Build C++ Project on Network Drive

Tags: c++, networking, visual-studio-2008, compiler-errors, virtual-machine

The short of it is, I have VMs for building different scenarios of software. I do not wish to snapshot the code as it is backup elsewhere so I am storing all my code on the host PC and only building/testing in VMs to save space. Unfortunately I am receiving program database update errors when I try to build from a location mapped to the host hdd.
I know there is nothing wrong with the C++ projects as they build fine if moved inside the VM.

I have tried:
-cleaning/rebuilding
-removing the debug/release folders entirely
-checking out a copy of the source onto the host drive from within the VM

*Even when the idb and pdb files that the compiler complains about are created by VS, the problem persists.

How can I stop these C2471 errors when building from a non-local drive?

Comment: It seems like it must be a permissions or sharing issue, but my host does not have any of the files open (not even the folder) and I have ensured that my VM account(s) have full control/access to the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure as to why, but the issue seems to be related to using shared folders in VirtualBox. If the folders are referenced via a direct UNC path to the host machine it appears to work fine, but accessing through a shared folder (mapped or unmapped to a drive letter) doesn't appear to have the correct permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, problem in the files that was created by compiler at previus build. Try to remove `Debug` (or `Release`) folder and build project again.

Comment: I have tried this and many other things. I will amend my description to include some examples of what I've already tried. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Consider updating MSVS on at least one VM

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you referring to moving to 2010+ or a particular hotfix or ...? I'm running VS2008 SP1 to be precise.

Comment: VS 2010 ? No, it is so radical. Try first hot fix - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/946040

Comment: The archived link for that hotfix is not no longer valid, but I think it is included in SP1 so it should already be applied to my install.

Comment: I have no more ideas. So, try shifting to VS2010+